# What elements can I use to move a whole div down an area?

Tags: html, css

I am currently creating a layout for my webpage, I am wondering how I can move a whole div down an area so it doesn't collide with my 2 header divs.

Here is the current layout: 
http://imageshack.com/a/img633/7291/rpBirr.png

Here is the current HTML/CSS: http://imageshack.com/a/img908/1561/tTxSBP.png

Is there somehow an element that can turn my content div solid so it doesn't do this?

Comment: Please, do not submit your code as an image. Use text and fiddles when possible.

Comment: Try adding `clear:both` to .content class. Also if you would define max width parameters in the css for wrapper divs it will be much easier for you. `div` started exactly above `<footer>` remains un-closed - which could result in problems.

Comment: it work perfectly thankyou and thanks for the reminder I will stop using images for the next time

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this approach will get what you want:

```
.content{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    margin-top:100px;
}
```

Also don't post your code as an image, it makes our job of helping you much harder and people tend not to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Well what you need is margin. Add margin styles to the appropriate element and your job will be done.